# General Rule for calculating solutions to $ax+by=1$ where $(a,b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

A friend and I are in an intro to number theory class at UK and were struggling to prove the theorem that states that for two relatively prime integers $a$ and $b$ there exist integers x and y which satisfy the equation $ax+by=1$. We have now proven the theorem but while attempting to prove it began generating lists of relatively prime pairs with the same difference i.e. $(2,7)$, $(3,8)$, $(4,9)$..., and noticed patterns emerging in the solutions such as for differences of $5$:

```
(a,b)  (x,y)
(2,7)  (-3,1)
(3,8)  (3,-1)
(4,9)  (-2,1)
(6,10) (2,-1)
```

We are attempting to find a rule which will quickly generate a solution for any given pair, even of large numbers, not only for the differences of $5$ but for every given difference n. Any suggestions? Have you heard of this before?

Comment: sorry the part in the middle looks a little confusing let me clarify it should read as for (2,7), (x,y)=(-3,1), for (3,8), (x,y)=(3,-1) so on and so forth

Comment: Thank you. That's much better.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Try extended Euclide algorithm and [Bézout coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity).

Comment: right I understand this but i do not understand how this goes into predicting based upon a given difference n. I understand the idea of getting a single pair from the extended algorithm but I am personally more interested in the side about the patterns occur in these differences